# Turning windows application to web application via activeX

Tags: windows, activex

I have an existing windows desktop application and I wish to turn it to a web application as fast as possible, without rewriting the application.

Is it possible to somehow compile the application as an Active-X application and then I will have all the functionality 'out of the box'?

If not, what are the obstacles (apart from security loopholes)?
If so, what is the best way to do it?

Remark: I have never programmed in Active-X before so I might be missing something basic.

Answer (score 0):

Active X is essentially COM. See [here](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=145&t=Limitations_of_Web_Applications) for some of things that will be restricted and thus your 'app' will not be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at

[Web Forms User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[Hosting .NET Windows Forms Controls in IE](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030610.htm)